# Copying remotely over ansible with wildcards on windows

Tags: windows, ansible

Actually I'm trying to "install" (just extract and move to my prefered folder) Perl on Windows over ansible.

The package will be copied as tar.gz to the windows system and will be extracted twice, as windows interpretes tar.gz files a bit different (first extract tar.gz to tar file, then extract the tar file).

The source code will be extracted to C:\Perl\perl-5.30.0\ and I want to move the files from there to C:\Perl.

As the files are remote, I'm using "win_copy" module with "remote_src: yes" option.

Files are copying now with:

```
  - name: Get Perl files for copying on Windows
    win_find:
      paths: '{{ perldir }}\perl-{{ perlversion }}'
    register: perl_move_files

  - name: Copy Perl files to main dir on Windows
    win_copy:
      src: '{{ item.path }}'
      dest: '{{ perldir }}\'
      remote_src: yes
    with_items:
      - '{{ perl_move_files.files }}'
```

But ansible is copying only files and not the subdirectories with all files under it. How can I manage this for all files AND subdirectories?

Maybe some experts will read this?

Thanks and regards,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found another module which works better for that case: win_robocopy (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_robocopy_module.html)

```
  - name: Copy Perl files to main dir over Robocopy on Windows
    win_robocopy:
      src: '{{ perldir }}\perl-{{ perlversion }}'
      dest: '{{ perldir }}'
      recurse: yes
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

fileglob is used to find a match in the local server. For remote server you need to first find the files and then copy.

```
---
 - name: Find files 
   win_find:
    paths: '{{ perldir }}\perl-{{ perlversion }}'
   register: perl_files
 - name: Copy
   win_copy:
      src: '{{ item.path }}'
      dest: '{{ perldir }}\'
      remote_src: yes
   with_items: "{{perl_files.files}}"
```

Note: This code is not tested.

Comment: Edit my question post because of too much to say :)

Comment: what was the error message? cant find error in the edit.

Comment: ```
{u'isdir': False, u'extension': u'.h', u'isreadonly': False, u'checksum': u'd05f38971ae16eff9447714e451053dd31a8bc6b', u'size': 10541, u'creationtime': 1557575420, u'filename': u'zaphod32_hash.h', u'lastaccesstime': 1557575420, u'attributes': u'Archive', u'islnk': False, u'lastwritetime': 1557575420, u'owner': u'BUILTIN\\\\Administrators', u'path': u'C:\\\\Perl\\\\perl-5.30.0\\\\zaphod32_hash.h', u'isarchive': True, u'ishidden': False, u'isshared': False}]"}
```

Comment: So I've tried it also with 
```
  with_items:
      - '{{ perldir }}\perl-{{ perlversion }}\{{ perl_move_files.files.filename }}'
```
Then ansible means: "'list object' has no attribute 'filename'"

Comment: Can you please try once again with src: '{{ item.path }}'

Comment: Than I'll get this error:
```
The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'path'
```
The code:  - name: Copy Perl files to main dir on Windows
    win_copy:
      src: '{{ item.path }}'
      dest: '{{ perldir }}'
      remote_src: yes
    with_items:
      - '{{ perldir }}\perl-{{ perlversion }}\{{ perl_move_files.files }}'
```
```

Comment: I was just wrong by handling the dest param in win_copy module. Now it works but next problem is comming. See edit in question

Comment: If path is a directory, it is copied recursively. In this case, if path ends with "/", only inside contents of that directory are copied to destination. Otherwise, if it does not end with "/", the directory itself with all contents is copied.

Comment: In win_find it doesn't end with a "\" - so when I understand right, it should work with subdirs...

``  - name: Get Perl files for copying on Windows
    win_find:
      paths: '{{ perldir }}\perl-{{ perlversion }}'
    register: perl_move_files
```

Comment: sorry i was talking about the win_copy src path